# area chart fill-opacity issue in c3js and angular 2

Tags: html, css, angular, c3.js

I have created a line chart using c3.js and angular 2.But i am getting a unwanted black area in line chart.It's working more likely chart with filled area.I am trying to override it's css property..."fill-opacity". but it's not working.Give me a solution.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJiWh.png)

Comment: Please add some code samples

Answer (score 2):

Due to c3 lib CSS is missing. CSS file for C3 chart .

https://rawgit.com/masayuki0812/c3/master/c3.css.

Comment: what is the Error?

Comment: It will be you're missing the c3.css file. Check your console to see if it is getting loaded and is in the right place. Check the actual path element for the line to see if the `.c3 path` rule with `fill: none` is being applied.

Answer (score 1):

copy past css into your bar-chart.component.css and add encapsulation in decorator as shown in e.g. 
It will definitely work :->

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as c3 from 'c3';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bar-chart',
  templateUrl: './bar-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bar-chart.component.css'], //copy and paste css here
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None     //add this line in your component
})

export class BarChartComponent implements OnInit {
  jsonData : any[] = [];
  jsonKeys : any = {};
  jsonAxis : any = {};

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.jsonData = [
                      {name: 'www.site1.com', upload: 200, download: 150, total: 400},
                      {name: 'www.site2.com', upload: 100, download: 300, total: 400},
                      {name: 'www.site3.com', upload: 300, download: 200, total: 500},
                      {name: 'www.site4.com', upload: 400, download: 100, total: 500},
                    ];
    this.jsonKeys = {
                      x: 'name', // it's possible to specify 'x' when category axis
                      value: ['upload', 'download'],
    };
    this.jsonAxis = {
                      x : {
                          type : 'category'
                      }
    };

    let chart = c3.generate({
      bindto: '#chart',
      data: {
        json: this.jsonData,
        keys: this.jsonKeys,
      },
      axis: this.jsonAxis,
    });
   }
}
```