# C3 chart rendering background artifacts

Tags: angular, c3.js

I am having an issue with a C3 chart rendering some of its background black. See image. I have tweaked the data density and am getting the same results. I have removed css-defined background colors to no avail.

[image]
This is in an Angular 2 application. Has anyone seen this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I was including the c3.js css file in my component. The issue was that I was not using proper view encapsulation. After adding

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

to my Component definition, the styles started to be applied properly.

Comment: You should add that as an answer to the question I linked to, it's very probably the same issue

Answer (score 0):

It could be similar to [area chart fill-opacity issue in c3js and angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41822866/area-chart-fill-opacity-issue-in-c3js-and-angular-2)

Whenever this in seen c3, it's generally because the c3.css file hasn't been included which sets paths to `fill:none` with this rule:

```
.c3 path, .c3 line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000; }
```

I don't know whether angular2 has anything to do with it though, not my area of expertise. Maybe it's causing the css file to be withheld somehow looking at that linked q?